# TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, telegram, telegram-bot

The code was taken from github and implemented by a developer and deployed in AWS and on-premise. It works fine on both but gives below error in GCP. I am an Admin with very minimum python skills trying to implement it in GCP.  Did OS level tuning as mentioned by google but still same error. It is working normally but when it goes idle for 2 hours and receives any message then immediately it crashes.

```
2020-09-11 04:52:29,282 (util.py:75 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionE
rror occurred, args=(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(1
04, 'Connection reset by peer')),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py"
, line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/alex/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py"
, line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/alex/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py"
, line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Looks like you have a problem connecting to AWS. Probably an issue with the AWS firewall or white listing IP addresses.You need to check your AWS account to see what access it permitted.

Comment: Mike it works fine in AWS and even in GCP. Problem is when it goes idle for 2 hours in GCP then it crashes but its not happening in AWS or on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be investigated by the Google product team.

Then I would suggest forwarding this through a [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for further support. or you can open a ticket with [Google Cloud support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) (For free users [this link](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/support/)) so that we may investigate this issue further.